# spring boot url предыдущего сайта

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

Как в маппинге узнать с url пред страницы? Если использовать `HttpServletRequest().getHeader("referer")` то работает правильно только если заходить с того-же сайта, но если зайти с гугла или фейсбука, то выдает `null`